# Encoding issue between Excel CSV and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I'm developing a tool which inserts a CSV file created from an Excel file, into a MySQL database using PHP.
I got a serious encoding issue. For example the word :

```
numéro
```

becomes the following string :

```
num├â┬®ros
```

I've never seen such an encoding problem.
I tried to force conversion to UTF8 or ANSI : it's not better. Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `$con->set_charset("utf8");` just before your query, while replacing `$con` with your DB connection variable. This page may also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: IIRC, normally, MS Excel uses UTF16LE

Comment: I just user PHP to generate the request into a SQL file that I run thanks to the `exec()` function. Can I add `SET NAMES 'utf8';` into the request ?

Comment: You can try it, I can't see why not. But Mark's comment makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems to work only if :

- I let the native Excel CSV encoding (which seems to be ANSI according to Notepad++)
- I add `SET NAMES 'UTF8';` before my INSERT SQL request

Hope it will work durably !